# Unit Testing Graph API SDK c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to mock this graph API SDK code.

```
 private readonly GraphServiceClient _client;
 IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage msgs = await _client.Users[userEmailAddress].MailFolders[folderNameId]
                .Messages.Request().WithMaxRetry(5).WithMaxRetry(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5, 0)).Filter(emailFilter).GetAsync();
```

I am not sure how to mock a chained of index properties and method in a single line. I tried to do the following but does not work. Any advices? Thanks.

```
  private Mock<IGraphServiceClient> mockGsc;
  mockGsc = new Mock<IGraphServiceClient>();
  mockGsc.Setup(x => x.Users[It.IsAny<string>()].MailFolders[It.IsAny<string>].Messages.Request().WithMaxRetry(It.IsAny<int>).WithMaxRetry(It.IsAny<TimeSpan>).Filter(It.IsAny<string>).GetAsync()).Returns< IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage>();
```

Comment: In terms of mocking, just have one method that makes all graph calls and use dependency injection to substitute an arbitrary mock.

You can save the json responses of some real calls and have your mock return those. It should work fine with your favorite mock / DI framework or just make custom mocks.

You can look at the actual dot netsdk for graph for examples: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/tree/dev/tests/Microsoft.Graph.Core.Test/Mocks that uses Moq: https://github.com/moq/moq

Comment: Since the answer and the comment are the same I'm posting this here to help anyone looking for the moved link: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/tree/dev/tests/Microsoft.Graph.DotnetCore.Core.Test/Mocks

Answer (score 1):

In terms of mocking, just have one method that makes all graph calls and use dependency injection to substitute an arbitrary mock. You can save the json responses of some real calls and have your mock return those. It should work fine with your favorite mock / DI framework or just make custom mocks. You can look at the actual dot netsdk for graph for [examples](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/tree/dev/tests/Microsoft.Graph.Core.Test/Mocks):  that uses [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq):

Comment: i think the example page that you sent is not working

Comment: I don't know why they changed the project URL, but here's where @Dev appeared to be linking you to: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/tree/dev/tests/Microsoft.Graph.DotnetCore.Core.Test/Mocks